# django - пагинация страниц без перезагрузки, как сделать?

Tags: python, ajax, django, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.
Я сделал пагинацию для комментариев (расположено посередине страницы) - все работает, но проблема в том, что при переходе на вторую страницу комментариев она перезагружается полностью и уходит вверх, чтоб посмотреть комментарии второй страницы нужно делать прокрутку до середины где они и находятся. Как сделать, чтоб при переходе на другую страницу комментариев вся страница не перезагружалась? Пока поставил якорь, но это не решает проблему т.к. страница всеравно перезагружается при переходе по комментариям.

Как это сделать с помощью аякса или других скриптов или может есть какая батарейка для джанги уже готовая посоветуйте плиз!

Comment: https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Можно возвращать значение скролла при перезагрузке

```
let cords = ['scrollX','scrollY']; 
window.addEventListener('unload', e => cords.forEach(cord => localStorage[cord] = window[cord])); 
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
    if (localStorage[cords[0]]) {
        window.scroll(...cords.map(cord => localStorage[cord]));
        cords.forEach(cord => localStorage.removeItem(cord));
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

можно используя якорную ссылку, добавлять ее ключ в тот же get запрос при переходе на другую страницу. (добавлять в возвращаемом функцией url)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]